# bigQuery not supporting milliseconds timestamps

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a value in my csv file for timetamp as '1522865628160'. When I load the data in bigQuery where this field type is timestamp, it saves the timestamp as '1522865628160000'. so when I query like

```
select * from <tablename> limit 1
```

it gives me error

> Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1522865628160000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field timestamp"

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you tried to load your UNIX timestamp data into a *timestamp* column in BigQuery.  A BigQuery timestamp column is *not* the same thing as a UNIX timestamp.  The latter is just a numerical value representing the number of seconds since the start of the UNIX epoch in 1970.

So the fix here would be to load your data into an `INT64` (or `INTEGER` if you are using legacy) column.  From there, you may convert your UNIX timestamp to a bona fide date or timestamp.

There is a `MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP()` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#msec_to_timestamp) which can convert an integer number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch to a bona fide timestamp, e.g.

```
SELECT MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1522865628160)

2018-04-04 11:13:48 UTC
```

Comment: Oh the issue is, I would like to use it as a partition column based on date, the only column I have is the timestamp column in my data, so I would like to use it as my partition column.

Comment: @Nipun This is a totally different question, and probably belongs in  question other than this one.  If you need a formal timestamp column, then use `MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP`, or create a new column and populate it.

Comment: Let me add a separate question for this

Comment: Can you help me out with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286217/bigquery-not-dealing-with-timestamp-in-millisecond-with-partition-column