# BigQuery not dealing with timestamp in millisecond with partition column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a unix timestamp column which is represented in millisecond in my csv file. Now when I insert this data in my bigQuery table and query it I get this error

[bigQuery not supporting milliseconds timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285385/bigquery-not-supporting-milliseconds-timestamps)

Now I would like to make this column as a partition column. 
I have a few questions 
1) Even if I save it as int64, how can I make a partition column on this field?
2) I would like to avoid duplicate tables.

Comment: I'm not a BigQuery expert, but [according to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) you need a date or timestamp column for the partition.  So just populate a timestamp column with your data.

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamp data is represented in milliseconds, you won't be able to properly create the Partitioned table. Instead you should use a "TIMESTAMP or DATE column" as stated by @TimBiegeleisen. Timestamp [will use microsecond precision](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type). Once your column is in microsecond you can use something like the following to create the partitioned table:

```
bq load --schema <your-timestamp-column>:TIMESTAMP,<some-other-column>:FLOAT --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV --time_partitioning_field=<your-timestamp-column> <your-dataset>.<your-table> <your-csv-file>
```

(use `--skip_leading_rows` if you have the column names in the csv file.)

Query your table using Standard SQL not Legacy, as you can see [in official docs here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions):

> You cannot use legacy SQL to query partitioned tables or to write query results to partitioned tables.