# Pubsub to BQ Dataflow template is not parsing RECORD type data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using this Dataflow template "Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery" to parse json schema with RECORD type data structure.
Sample Example :

```
{
"url":"/i?session_duration=61&app_key=123456&device_id=gdfttyty&sdk_name=javascript_native_web&sdk_version=18.04",
"body":
    {
    "session_duration":"61",
    "app_key":"eyrttyuyyu78jkjk",
    "device_id":"h1bh41yptik1vtwr8",
    "sdk_name":"javascript_native_web",
    "sdk_version":"18.04",
    "timestamp":"1597057884636",
    "hour":"10",
    "dow":"1"
    },
"app_key":"eyrttyuyyu78jkjk",
"timestamp":"1597057884636",
"ip_address":"0.0.0.0"
}
```

Schema Defined in BigQuery is as :

```
[

   {
      "name":"url",
      "type":"STRING",
      "mode":"NULLABLE"
   },
   {
      "name":"body",
      "type":"RECORD",
      "mode":"REPEATED",
      "fields":[
         {
            "name":"session_duration",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         },
         {
            "name":"app_key",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         },
         {
            "name":"device_id",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         }, 
         {
            "name":"sdk_name",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         },
         {
            "name":"sdk_version",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         }, 
         {
            "name":"timestamp",
            "type":"TIMESTAMP",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         }, 
         {
            "name":"hour",
            "type":"TIME",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         },      
         {
            "name":"dow",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         }

      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"app_key",
      "type":"STRING",
      "mode":"NULLABLE"
   },
   {
      "name":"timestamp",
      "type":"STRING",
      "mode":"NULLABLE"
   },
   {
      "name":"ip_address",
      "type":"STRING",
      "mode":"NULLABLE"
   }
]
```

Error Message:

```
{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"","message":"Repeated record added outside of an array.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}
```

If I parse data without RECORD type , it gets parsed correctly and in appropriate bigquery table but with RECORD type it gets ingested to bq generated <error_records> table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to successfully insert your sample into BigQuery using the Dataflow `Pub/Sub to Bigquery` template by applying some modifications:

- I included the repeated field in an array by putting it inside square brackets `[...]`
- The `body.timestamp` value is invalid. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285489) about the difference between the BigQuery `TIMESTAMP` data type and the UNIX timestamp. You have some options on how to handle this depending on what you want to do with this timestamp. If you don't need it for analysis you can easily change the data type of the field to `INT64` or `STRING` as you you have done with the `timestamp` column of the table.

So the message should be like this:

```
{
"url":"/i?session_duration=61&app_key=123456&device_id=gdfttyty&sdk_name=javascript_native_web&sdk_version=18.04",
"body": [
    {
    "session_duration":"61",
    "app_key":"eyrttyuyyu78jkjk",
    "device_id":"h1bh41yptik1vtwr8",
    "sdk_name":"javascript_native_web",
    "sdk_version":"18.04",
    "timestamp":"1597057884636",
    "hour":"10",
    "dow":"1"
    }],
"app_key":"eyrttyuyyu78jkjk",
"timestamp":"1597057884636",
"ip_address":"0.0.0.0"
}
```

and the schema with the changed data type for the `body.timestamp` field like this:

```
[

   ...
   
   ,
   {
      "name":"body",
      "type":"RECORD",
      "mode":"REPEATED",
      "fields":[
         
         ...

         , 
         {
            "name":"timestamp",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         }, 
         
         ...
         
      ]
   },
   
   ...
   
]
```

Comment: Thanks, small tweak of adding square brackets did work in sample data.
Could you explain why this is required as the input we are getting is not having square brackets?

Comment: I'm happy that it worked for you! It would be nice if you could also accept my answer since it help you resolve your issue. As for why, [this is how](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#example_schema) the `REPEATED` fields should be provided in BigQuery according to the official documentation.